# dependent combo in classic ASP and Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, drop-down-menu

Please can you suggest me an example in classic asp and ajax to make dependent combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long before the concept of AJAX was formalised, I was using a technique called [XML Data Islands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923725.aspx) to achieve this kind of functionality. Obviously, there are a number of AJAX frameworks and scripts that can achieve similar result, but this is just the tried-and-tested technique that I have used for years in my legacy applications.

I can't quickly find any suitable articles, so I've dug up some of my old code. Basically, when you set the value of the parent control, you run some javascript that sends a request to a separate ASP page. This page queries the DB to get determine the data that will be used to populate the child control.

This second page returns the results as XML, which is stored and manipulated in an XML Data Island in your primary page. The calling javascript then parses the returned XML and populates the child control.

First we have the javascript calls from the primary control:

```
<tr>
                    <td>Customer:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="CustomerID" NAME="CustomerID" 
                            onfocus="javascript:populateCombo(fProcess.CustomerID.value)" 
                            onChange="javascript:populateCombo(fProcess.CustomerID.value)"  
                            onkeypress="javascript:populateCombo(fProcess.CustomerID.value);">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Depot:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="depot" id="depot" size="1"  alt="Depot">
                            <option value="" selected >&lt;Select Depot&gt;</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Then we have the javascript which makes the call to the second page (which retrieves the data from the DB):

```
// Fill combo with XML data
function populateCombo(par) {
    var currNode;

    XMLID.async = false;

    // Change Data Island source
    strQuery = "Select LocationID, LocationName from Locations where CustomerID='" + par + "' and Active = 1 Order By LocationName";
    XMLID.SRC="/fxdb/common/xmlQuery.asp?strQuery=" + strQuery;

    // Get all "names" from XML data
    objNodeList = XMLID.getElementsByTagName("LocationName");
    objNodeListID= XMLID.getElementsByTagName("LocationID");


    // Fill combo with names
    for (var i=0; i < objNodeList.length; i++) {
        fProcess.depot.options[i]=new Option(objNodeList.item(i).text,objNodeListID.item(i).text);
    }

    // Delete extra entries
    while ( objNodeList.length < fProcess.depot.options.length) {
        fProcess.depot.options[(fProcess.depot.options.length - 1)] = null;
    } 

}
```

And finally, the page that queries the DB itself.

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%
'  Declare all variables.
Option Explicit
Dim strSql,objRS,objField
Dim sConn, oConn
Dim strName, strValue


' Buffer and output as XML.
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"

' Start our XML document.
Response.Write "<?xml version=""1.0""?>" & vbCrLf

' Set SQL and database connection string.

set oConn=server.createobject("adodb.connection") 
sConn=Application("Connection")
oConn.Open sConn
strSQL = Request.QueryString("strQuery")

set objRS=oConn.execute(strSQL)

' Output start of data.
Response.Write "<database>" & vbCrLf

' Loop through the data records.
While Not objRS.EOF
    ' Output start of record.
    Response.Write "<record>" & vbCrLf
    ' Loop through the fields in each record.
    For Each objField in objRS.Fields
        strName  = objField.Name
        strValue = objField.Value
        If Len(strName)  > 0 Then strName = Server.HTMLEncode(strName)
        If Len(strValue) > 0 Then strValue = Server.HTMLEncode(strValue)
        Response.Write "<" & strName & ">" & vbCrLf
        Response.Write strValue & vbCrLf 
        Response.Write "</" & strName & ">" & vbCrLf
    Next
    ' Move to next city in database.
    Response.Write "</record>" & vbCrLf
    objRS.MoveNext
Wend

' Output end of data.
Response.Write "</database>" & vbCrLf
%>
```

Edit: Oops! I forgot the all-important XML Data Island itself - add this after your Body tag.

```
<!-- Data Island-->
<XML ID="XMLID"></XML>
```

Comment: Note XML Islands are an IE only concept however the general principle can be applied using XmlHTTPRequest.

Comment: Hi CJM, thank you very much... it's exactly what I was looking for... but it gives me this javascript error: "XMLID is not defined"... what can I do?

Comment: @AWJ: Yeah, I was led to believe the same, but nevertheless works in FF for us. Also it's used in an corporate intranet environment, so (for me) there has never been any urgency to convert the script to use XMLHTTRequest - but I acknowledge your point.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [solution using ajaxed](http://www.ajaxed.org/article/Creating-dependent-dropdowns/20/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the word you were missing from "Asp Combobox ajax" is "Cascading".  The concept where the set of items available in one combox depends on a value selected in a previous combox or some other field.

There don't seem to be any good simple examples of this in ASP alone.  However in combination with jquery you could try this link, [jquery.cascade cascading values from forms](http://devlicio.us/blogs/mike_nichols/archive/2008/05/25/jquery-cascade-cascading-values-from-forms.aspx).

That leaves you only needing to create the ASP pages that generate the simple JSON required.

Comment: Yes Anthony, I looking for "Cascading combobox"! The concept is this, but I wish to find a code example in classic asp, not in asp.net

Comment: @Davide:  Oops didn't notice the content of the page was ASP.NET not ASP.  There doesn't seem to be any simple examples of this in Classic.